# 'ls | grep -c' and full path

Tags: linux, grep, ls

Can I use `ls | grep -c /full/path/to/file` to count the occurrences of a file, but while executing the command from a different directory than where the files I'm looking for are?

Let's say I want to look how many *.txt* files I have in my "results" directory. Can I do something like `ls | grep -c /full/path/to/results/*.txt` while I'm in another directory?

Although I have *.txt* files in that directory, I always get a zero when I run the command from another directory :( What's happening? Can I only use `ls` for the current directory?

Comment: you can pass the parent directory as a parameter to the ls command (ls /parent/directory), or maybe I don't get what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ls <dirname>`. Plain *[ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)* defaults only to the current directory.

What you are trying to do can be accomplished by `find <dir> -name "*.txt" | grep -c txt` or `find <dir> -name "*.txt" | wc -l`

But you can do `ls * | grep \.txt$` as well. Please read the manual to find the differences.

Comment: I agree, `find` is the proper tool here, not `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

- [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) accepts regular expressions, not glob. `/foo/bar/*.txt` is a glob. Try `/foo/bar/.*\.txt`
- also `ls` lists files and directories under your current directory. It will not list the `full path`. Do some tests, and you will see it easily.
- `ls` may output results in a single line, and this could make your `grep -c` give an incorrect result. Because grep does line-based matching.

Comment: @all 

Thank you all. Unfortunately I can't find a solution, whatever I'm doing is wrong. I have tried everything suggested and I always get a zero. ls <dirname> gives me a syntax error no matter what syntax I use. Thank you all for your time though.

Comment: that is because you are using ls <dirname> literally. in commands, <dirname> means a valid directory name you are going to replace it with. in your case you need to run this command `ls /full/path/to/results/*.txt | grep -c \.txt$`  OR  `ls /full/path/to/results/*.txt | wc -l`